# spring web application - html button - post method outside form - 404 ERROR

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I`m trying to send post request from JSP view to Controller by Button "onClick" method but i getting 404 Error that the RequestMapping is not sign, why is that?

HomeController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showSelectedRequest/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loadRequestProducts(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {

    logger.debug("HomeController.RequestIdSelected() - Start");
    logger.debug("HomeController.RequestIdSelected: id: " + id);
    model.addAttribute("RequestIdSelected", id);

    logger.debug("HomeController.RequestIdSelected() - Done");
    return "/home";

}
```

Home.jsp:

```
<form action="${contextPath}/requestlist" method="post">    
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Show request
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <c:forEach items="${requestDTOList}" var="requestDTO">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ${requestDTO.getId()}
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${requestDTO.getName()}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-info"  onclick="post(/showSelectedRequest/${requestDTO.getId()})">Query</button>
                    <input type="hidden"  name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace your button and onclick method with a simple <input type="submit" value="Query" /> ?

Comment: @L01c How can i do that? my action of the form is diffrent action.. and the "Query" option is to load data from another request...

Comment: @Lo1 Thank you I updating Answer now, you gave me an idea :)

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a form, the action field is what will be executed when you will click on the input of type "submit".

As a solution you can modify your code as follow:

```
<form action="${contextPath}/showSelectedRequest/${requestDTO.getId()}" method="post">  
    // Form elements ...
    <input type="submit" value="Query" />
</form>
```